# Post array and variable to view

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I want to post an array and a variable to view. Here is my variable.

```
$ausgabeSpieltag = $saisonMaxSpieltagEins;
```

And here is my array and the way like I post it to view at the moment. But now I need additional the variable in the ->with part.

```
$spieltagSpiel = Spielplan::where('Spieltag', '=', $ausgabeSpieltag)->where('Abgeschlossen', '=', 0)->get();
    foreach($spieltagSpiel as $spieltagSpielOutput){
        $heimName = Verein::where('V_ID', '=', $spieltagSpielOutput->Heimmannschaft)->first();
        $gastName = Verein::where('V_ID', '=', $spieltagSpielOutput->Gastmannschaft)->first();
        $resultData[$spieltagSpielOutput->Spielplan_ID] =  $heimName->Name. ' - ' .$gastName->Name;
    }
return view('spielplan')->with('alleSpiele', $resultData);
```

Here is my output blade

```
<h3>Dateneingabe</h3>

{{$ausgabeSpieltag}}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
        <label for="">Spielauswahl</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="spiele" id="spiele">
        @foreach( $alleSpiele as $alleSpieleKey => $alleSpieleName )
            <option value="{{ $alleSpieleKey }}">
                {{ $alleSpieleName }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
        <label for="">Teamauswahl</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="spiel" id="spiel">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
        Hier kommt der Abgeschlossen Button hin
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything is working excluded my {{$ausgabeVariable}}. In the variable is only 1 number and i want to have this in my H3 after Dateneingabe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should easily pass multiple variable with `compact` in laravel like :

```
$alleSpiele = $resultData;
return view('spielplan',compact('alleSpiele','ausgabeSpieltag'));
```

Comment: I want to put out in blade {{yourVariable}} but it won't work. How to do this?

Comment: @HansMuff Please show you blade file where you put {{yourVariable}}

Comment: @HansMuff And yourVariable  means which variable you need in view file.

Comment: I made an update in my question. Hope you understand what I mean

Comment: @HansMuff Please check my updated answer

Comment: @HansMuff And my updated answer not your solution then please put dd($ausgabeSpieltag) in your function where you define $ausgabeSpieltag variable

Comment: dd(§ausgabeSpieltag) is see only number 3 in my browser and this number 3, I need in the H3

Comment: @HansMuff and are you try with my updated answer ?

Comment: @HansMuff Please check 3 is display or not on your view

Comment: @HansMuff Glad to help and if my answer is you r solution then please up vote to my answer

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
return view('spielplan')->with('alleSpiele', $resultData)->with('variable',$variable);
```

or you can use compact

```
return view('spielplan')->with(compact('alleSpiele', 'variable'));
```

or you can send your data withing an array like this

```
 return view('spielplan')->with('data',['alleSpiele'=>$alleSpiele, 'variable'=>$variable]);
```

where **alleSpiele** is an array and **variable** is a variable you have created

Answer (score 1):

You can send data to view in the following array

```
return view('spielplan',['alleSpiele' => $resultData]);
```